# Is it ever safe, to execute getIntent().getExtras() before Activity.super.onCreate()

Tags: java, android

If we turn on "Don't keep activites" and "No background processes" in Developer options, we can produce the following behaviour easily.

- `Activity.super.onCreate()` will trigger `Fragment.onCreate()`
- Activity will only initialize data structure after `Activity.super.onCreate()`
- If `Fragment.onCreate()` is accessing data structure in Activity, crash will happen as data structure is not being initialized yet.

This behaviour is described in [Why Fragment's onCreate() is sometimes called prior to Activity's onCreate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297978/why-fragments-oncreate-is-sometimes-called-prior-to-activitys-oncreate)

We just change our code from

---

### Accessing Bundle after Activity.super.onCreate

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        final Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        this.dataStructure = bundle.getParcelable(...);
    }
}
```

to

---

### Accessing Bundle before Activity.super.onCreate

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        this.dataStructure = bundle.getParcelable(...);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

---

We have done intensive testing and it works fine.

However, under Firebase Crashlytics, we saw very minor edge cases, `getIntent().getExtras()` is returning null sometimes?

I was wondering, is it caused by the fact that I am accessing `getIntent().getExtras()` before `Activity.super.onCreate()`, or that might due to other reasons?

Comment: This might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981238/do-something-before-oncreate